# Converting a int to char and then back to int - doesn't give same result always

Tags: java, unicode, char, int

I am trying to get a `char` from an `int` value > `0xFFFF`. But instead, I always get back the same `char` value, that when cast to an `int`, prints the value `65535` (`0xFFFF`).

I couldn't understand why it is generating symbols for unicode > `0xFFFF`.

```
int hex = 0x10FFFF;
char c = (char)hex;
System.out.println((int)c);
```

I expected the output to be `0x10FFFF`. Instead, the output comes back as `65535`.

Comment: What were you expecting?  Do you know the difference between an `int` and a `char`?

Comment: yeah i know the difference, but i am trying to generate a char whose UTF8 encoding gives me 4 bytes, which i am failed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, while an `int` is 4 bytes, a `char` is only 2 bytes. Thus, you can't represent all values in a `char` that you can in an `int`. Using a standard unsigned integer representation, you can only represent the range of values from `0` to `2^16 - 1 == 65535` in a 2-byte value, so if you convert any number outside that range to a 2-byte value and back, you'll lose data.

Answer (score 2):

int is 4 byte. char is 2 byte.
Your number was well within range an int can hold, but not which char can.
So when you converted that number to a char, it lost data and became the maximum a char can hold, which is what it printed i.e. 65535

Answer (score 2):

Your number was too big to be a char which is 2 bytes. But it was small enough where it fit in as an int which is 4 bytes. 65535 is the biggest amount that fits in a char so that's why you got that value. Also, if a char was big enough to fit your number, when you returned it to an int it might have returned the decimal value for 0x10FFFF which is 1114111.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I think you were expecting a Java `char` to be the same thing as a Unicode code point.  They are not the same thing.

The Java `char`, as already expressed by other answers, can only support code points that can be represented in 16 bits, whereas Unicode needs 21 bits to support all code points.

In other words, a Java `char` on its own, only supports Basic Multilingual Plane characters (code points <= `0xFFFF`).  In Java, if you want to represent a Unicode code point that is in one of the extended planes (code points > `0xFFFF`), then you need surrogate characters, or a pair of characters to do that.  This is how [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) works.  And, internally, this is how Java strings work as well.  Just for fun, run the following snippet to see how a single Unicode code point is actually represented by 2 characters if the code point is > `0xFFFF`:

```
// Printing string length for a string with 
// a single unicode code point: 0x22BED.
System.out.println("".length()); // prints 2, because it uses a surrogate pair.
```

If you want to safely convert an `int` value that represents a Unicode code point to a `char` (or `char`s to be more exact), and then convert it back to an `int` code point, you will have to use code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hex = 0x10FFFF;
    System.out.println(Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(hex)); // prints true because hex > 0xFFFF
    char[] surrogateChars = Character.toChars(hex);
    int codePointConvertedBack = Character.codePointAt(surrogateChars, 0);
    System.out.println(codePointConvertedBack); // prints 1114111
}
```

Alternatively, instead of manipulating `char` arrays, you can use a `String`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hex = 0x10FFFF;
    System.out.println(Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(hex)); // prints true because hex > 0xFFFF
    String s = new String(new int[] {hex}, 0, 1);
    int codePointConvertedBack = s.codePointAt(0);
    System.out.println(codePointConvertedBack); // prints 1114111
}
```

For further reading: [Java Character Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)